# Localization in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, localization

In Android Studio, I'm attempting to localize to Arabic, How can I translate true and false to Arabic words?`<string name="Chocolate_cream_order_summary">"كريمة الشكولاته:  "</string>`

Comment: This question seems to be more about translation than programming, and as such does not fall within the scope of this site as defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) under How to Create Default Resources. You will need to create separate resource files to store your translations so that the user can switch to them using their device's settings menu.

In your case, assuming your default is English, you would place the English version of your string in `res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<string name="Chocolate_cream_order_summary">Chocolate cream order summary</string>`
```

Then, you would create a separate folder and strings file, i.e. `res/values-ar/strings.xml` to store your Arabic translation:

```
<string name="Chocolate_cream_order_summary">"كريمة الشكولاته:  "</string>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the translation string by adding this tag in root,

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation"
```

You can refer more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html)